# Compilation failure child package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jbehave

I am trying to create simple Rest API app and I want to check it with jbehave framework, everything worked fine until I added dependency for image_capture project in my service_tests project.

In my code everything fine, my service_tests recognize image_capture classes but when I am trying to mvn clean install for parent app I am getting

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project service_tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
 for all packages from my image_capture project.

I am using IntelliJ, java 8 and spring boot for Rest API app.

I saw many answers from stackoverflow and did not succeed with one of them.

Thanks for help in advance.

My parent pom:

```
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>image_capture_parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>image_capture_parent</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <modules>
            <module>image_capture</module>
            <module>service_tests</module>
        </modules>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath />
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

My first child project:

        <parent>
        <artifactId>image_capture_parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>image_capture_parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>image_capture</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>reserve-tomcat-port</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <portNames>
                                <portName>tomcat.http.port</portName>
                            </portNames>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>        

My second child project ( for running jbehave tests):

         <parent>
        <artifactId>image_capture_parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>image_capture_parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>service_tests</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>image_capture_parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>image_capture</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>image_capture.com.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Disable unit tests -->
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <ignoreFailureInStories>false</ignoreFailureInStories>
                            <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason: Spring Boot classes is not accessible via dependencies as I understood. That a reason that my test app does not see spring boot classes while compiling via Maven. The solution is to use additional app, not spring boot app, that has class that represents spring boot Entity class.

I found some reference in this article: https://www.toptal.com/spring/top-10-most-common-spring-framework-mistakes

The solution that I used here is a Common Mistake number 2 from the article.